# Best practice in C++ - when should I divide my project into .h and .cpp files?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

I'm starting with a new project. 
I know, that the idea of dividing a project into .h and .cpp is good, but it's pretty annoying for me when writing and testing the code.

Is it a good practice to split my project into .h and .cpp while writing a new code?

Or is it better to write whole classes in .h and then split it into .h and .cpp (when my project is finished or nearly finished)?

Or should I write just new classes in .cpp files and then create individual .h files?

Comment: "Is it a good practice to split my project into .h and .cpp while writing a new code?". YES. Nothing else. Doing something else first is a) more work because you have no overview of the class and b) more work because you´ll have to change everything again after it is finished.

Comment: The only time I found it convenient to have everything in one .h file is when I am writing a templated class.

Comment: Act in haste(being lazy), repent at leisure.

Comment: In my experience, planning to do something "when my project is finished" means it will never happen ;)

Comment: Find a good excuse not to write `.cpp` files: make your all your code templated. (`.cpp` are for compilers to "write".)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In all but the most trivial projects, or some special header file only libraries it is good practice to split it up into separate .h and .cpp files. Apart from small private helper classes it is good practice to have a separate .h & .cpp file for each class. The exceptions are probably templates classes and interfaces which can be header file only.

Once you get into the habit it is not particularly annoying. In fact it makes managing the project easier.

Comment: Thank you :). is it true, that when I'm creating an interface I don't need .cpp file? (lack of implementation)

Comment: @TomDavies92 Yes, I happened to have just added that to my answer.

Answer (score 3):

You should *always* consider splitting your actual code and its declarations not only as a good practice, but also as a strict rule to apply. Unless you are writing templates, in which case both their declaration and definition will go in the header file (i.e `Boost`'s code, which is, for the most part of it, *template only*). But as it was mentioned in a comment, even when using templates, you can still separate *definition* and *declaration*.

This is recommended to avoid a lot of pain during development. Not doing so may put you in troubles. Notably, having your compiler recompile a whole bunch of stuff every time a change is made to the code in your header file, or because of multiple inclusions which would ultimately cause you hours of your time.

Comment: Even if you're writing templates, you should usually split the actual code and the declarations.  It's even good practice to put them in separate files, although often, just putting the implementation at the end of the header file is sufficient.

Comment: @JamesKanze Yes, you're obviously right. However, I mentionned it in order for the OP to not be confused when he will come across source codes such as boost's which is, for the most part of it, header only.

Answer (score 2):

.h files are usually used as external interfaces to your code, so expose as little as possible in them and hide implementation details in the .cpp file. Sometimes I put just a single function in the .h file and completely hide a class in the .cpp.

If you have circular dependencies or recursive data structures, you'll probably have problems if you don't split up your .h and .cpp files well.

You really only NEED to put everything in a .h if it's generic code (templates, contexpr, macros...)

Comment: You don't _need_ to put everything in a .h (or .hpp, or .hh -- I'd avoid .h for headers which aren't C compatible), even with templates.  On large projects, the usual practice is to put the implementation code of the template in a separate file, which is included at the end of the header---in the places I've worked, `.tcc` has been the usual extension for these (but then, `.cc` has been the usual extension for sources, and `.hh` for headers).

Comment: Sure, it's still transitively in the .h though, since including the .h will include the .tcc. I see your point though.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what problem you're tackling, and what your aiming for. The general convention is to use a pair of header and implementation files for each class. (Unless you're writing template classes, which have to go entirely into header files).

Now when you're just quickly testing something small, it's entirely appropriate to stick all the code in a single `cpp` file. But as soon as your project satisfies any of the following conditions:

- The project is more than a sigle algorithm/experiment
- Other developers will work on it
- The project will live (i.e. it will be developed, used and maintained) for some time

You should definitely stick to the convention.

Now I'll admit that it requires more effort, which can seem daunting - but there are also tools to help with this. For example, there is [Visual Assist](https://www.wholetomato.com/) for Visual Studio, which can help with adding member definitions to the corresponding `cpp` file, good editors support switching between header and implementation with a hotkey, etc.

There's also [LZZ](http://www.lazycplusplus.com/index.html), which allows you to keep all your code in a single file and have `h` and `cpp` files generated from that, although I wouldn't recommend that unless you already have a lot of experience working on larger projects.

Comment: In my experience, you'll usually write the header (including all associated documentation) first; you can't write the implementation until you know what the function is supposed to do.  (And you don't know anything that isn't written down, so things like pre-conditions have to be documented _before_ you start writing the actual implementation.)

Comment: @JamesKanze when developing a class, yes, definitely. But when I said "single cpp file" I was thinking along the lines of a single-file project, where you have your `main()` and all code called by it in a single place. All my small prototypical projects started like this. Of course I'll refactor into separate files in case I'll use the code for something "serious".